# Is it possible to add and remove $http interceptors at runtime?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to add and remove interceptors at runtime?
If so, how?

I want to be able to do this after the config phase, at anytime during app lifetime.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, no, but you could add an interceptor during the config phase, and change its behavior at runtime.